# weak * convergence of sequence of functions alternating between 1 and -1.

Tags: functional-analysis

i've been trying to solve the folllowing exercise:

Define on $H^\infty[0,1)$ the sequence of functions $h_n(x) = 1$ if $x \in [\frac{k}{2^n},\frac{k+1}{2^n}), k=2m$ and $-1$ otherwise. Check convergence in weak* topology and weak topology, compute limits if they exist.

I am currently at the first part of the problem, convergence in weak-*.
My thoughts so far:
$L^\infty[0,1)$  is isomorphic to $\big(L^1[0,1)\big) ^*$. So the related topology is given by the family of seminorms $P = \{ p_x | x \in L^1[0,1) \}$, and $p_x(\omega) = | \int_0^1 \omega(t) x(t) dt |$, with $\omega \in L^\infty[0,1)$ and $x \in L^1[0,1)$.

I think it's reasonable to check if the sequence converges to $0$. So we would then check whether $lim_{n \to \infty} | \int_0^1 \omega(t) x(t) dt | \to 0$ for all $x \in L^1[0,1).$ This is equal to \begin{equation}lim_{n\to \infty} \sum_{i=0}^{2^n-1} \int_\frac{i}{2^n}^{\frac{i+1}{2^n}} (-1)^i x(t)dt. \end{equation}. I'm not sure how to progress from this point. Is this a dead end? I think my reasoning so far is correct.

Comment: As a hint try first it first with the continuous functions on $[0,1]$ rather than all of $L^1$. Now use that these are dense in $L^1$.

Comment: Still better, start with a constant function on a segment $[a,b] \subset [0,1]$. Then with functions which are a sum of such functions. Then use the fact that continuous functions are uniformly continuous so can be approximated by piece-wise constant functions. Lastly use the fact that continuous functions are dense in $L^{1}[0,1]$

Comment: thanks. i also thought about the "denseness" argument, but im not sure how to use it. how do you conclude using the fact that the integral goes to 0 for a dense set of functions of L1?